# Can I show .webp images but allow users to download PNGs?

Tags: html, webp

I want to display `.webp` images on my website to cut down on download size and make my content appear faster. But I also want people to be able to right-click my images and download them to their computers.

But people downloading my images would prefer PNG files because those can be edited, loaded into Word etc.

Can I somehow display the `.webp` image by default, but have the users download a `.png` when they download the image?

So far I have:

```
  <picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="img/ImageToBeDisplayed.webp" />
    <source srcset="img/IfYouDoNotSupportWebp.png" />
    <img src="img/IfYouDoNotSupportWebp.png" />
  </picture>
```

But that still only downloads the .webp file if the browser supports it.

Comment: I wouldn’t expect this to be possible. Maybe you could provide a link to the PNG, though, either separately or wrapping/overlaying the image?